CMake's add_compile_definitions adds backslashes and extra quotes in my string
I want to add
-DGIT_COMMIT_INFO="`git log -1 --format='\"%ad %h\"' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`"

to the Makefile generated by CMake.
I tried some of the answers to this questions, but for some reason none seemed to work. So I thought I would go for a more basic approach and tried to use add_compile_definitions. However, regardless of how I use it, backslashes and extra quotation marks get added in the string written in CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/flags.make.
When I write add_compile_definitions(GIT_COMMIT_INFO="`git log -1 --format='\"%ad %h\"' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`") or add_compile_definitions(GIT_COMMIT_INFO="\`git log -1 --format='\"%ad %h\"' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\`"), I get -DGIT_COMMIT_INFO="\"\`git log -1 --format='\"%ad %h\"' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\`\"".
I tried various ways to escape the special characters, but then I get outputs that are even further from what I want.
How can I tell CMake to not escape the backticks and not add extra double quotes?

Are you 100% sure you want to add -DGIT_COMMIT_INFO="git.. text or do you want to add the result of executing a command git to GIT_COMMIT_INFO? Why  not execute git and get the result and assign the result? Is this XY question? to the Makefile what if you use ninja? What if you compile on windows? What if the command is executed in a git submodule? What if there is no git?

The command output, of course, but that's why there are backticks, no? (Am I misreading your comment?)

ninja/windows/git: I wish I could use something else than CMake :) but this is an internal tool that will always be in a specific git repo and compiled on one Linux server, so portability is not really an issue.

You can add the string by quoting the full word in cmake. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument .
add_compile_definitions(
   "GIT_COMMIT_INFO=\"`git log -1 --format='\\\"%ad %h\\\"' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`\""
)

I highly doubt that is your intention. I guess that your intention is to add the output of executing a git command to the preprocessor defines. You would execute git and get the output and assign the result.
find_package(Git REQUIRED)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} log -1 "--format='\\\"%ad %h\\\"'" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_INFO
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
    COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL 
)
add_compile_definitions("GIT_COMMIT_INFO=${GIT_COMMIT_INFO}")

Prefer target_compile_definitions over add_compile_definitions. Additionally, this will mess up caching, as add_compile_definitions adds the definition to all files after it at directory scope, all files will be recompiled each commit, even if nothing no file has changed and those files do not depend on the comimt.
Instead, you should configure_file with compile definition and #include that file only in files that depend on the commit, as then only these files will be recompiled, saving you build time. My first google hit for "git commit hash in cmake to C definition" resulted in https://jonathanhamberg.com/post/cmake-embedding-git-hash/ which showcases the process. Something along:
// git_version.h
#cmakedefine GIT_COMMIT_INFO

// CMakeLists.txt
find_package(Git REQUIRED)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} log -1 "--format='\\\"%ad %h\\\"'" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_INFO
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
    COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL 
)
configure_file(git_version.h.in git_version.h @ONLY)
target_include_directories(yourtarget PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/)


When using your 2nd or 3rd solution, does calling make update the commit info, or do I need to call cmake at every commit?

I just tried your first solution, and CMake still adds extra quotation marks and backslashes...

When using your 2nd or 3rd... calling cmake confuguration stage. CMake still adds extra quotation marks yes, cmake properly qoutes the arguments for the tool it is generating for, thats great and expected. You might be interested in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html .
